# Solve for f in the integral equation $f(t) = \sin(t) + \int f(s)ds $

Tags: real-analysis, integral-equations

Solve for f in the integral equation $$f(t) = \sin t + \int_{0}^{t} f(s)ds$$ using $ (V^nx)(t) =\int_{0}^{t} \frac{(t-s)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}x(s)ds $ to to  where V is the *Volterra operator* $V$ on $L^2(0,1)$ is an operator of integration such as the one shown below 
$$(Vx)(t) = \int_{0}^{t} x(s)ds, 0\leq t\leq 1$$

I tried integrating both sides from $0$ to $t$: $$\int_{0}^{t}f(s)ds = \int_{0}^{t} \sin(s) ds + \int_{0}^{t} \int_{0}^{s} f(s) ds = -\cos(t) + \cos(0) + (V^2f)(t) = 1 - \cos(0) + \int_{0}^{t} (t-s)f(s)ds $$

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the solution using the Volterra operator, but it should be fairly straightforward to just take the derivative. If you take there derivative, then you'll have:

$$ f'(t) = \cos(t) + f(t) $$

which is the same as:
$$ f'(t) - f(t) = \cos(t)$$

Use the integrating factor $e^{-t}$, and you'll find

$$e^{-t} f'(t)  - e^{-t}f(t) = (e^{-t} f(t))'$$

So, you have:

$$ (e^{-t} f(t))' = e^{-t} \cos(t)$$ 
If you integrate both sides, you'll be able to get the solution easily. For the Volterra approach, the right thing is probably not to integrate per se, but to use the fact $\int_0^t f(s) ds = f(t) - \sin(t)$ so simplify the expressions involving the Volterra operator.

Comment: Unless I've missed something, there is no guarantee that $f$ is differentiable.

Comment: Ah, that is a very good point that I did not even consider. But, if it is then this should work. But, you are probably right, there needs to be another solution.

Comment: It comes down to whether $\int_0^t f(s) ds$ is differentiable.

Comment: This kind of solution is consistent because it makes an assumption and then checks it. The thing to be worried about is not whether you've found a solution (you have) but whether the original problem without the additional assumption had a unique solution in the first place.

Comment: Right, so $f$ actually must be differentiable. Suppose $f$ is defined on the interval $[a,b]$.  The function $F(t) = \int_0^{t} f(s) ds $ is continuous, so $f$ must be continuous. But, since $f$ is continuous, the fundamental theorem of calculus tells us that $F$ is differentiable on $(a,b$, and so $f$ must be differentiable on $(a,b)$. So, the above analysis works on $(a,b)$.